# How to perform multiple time Window operation on Streaming DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have 3 columns in DataFrame:- [time:TimeStamp,col1:Double,col2:Double]
I want to perform following operation:

```
dataFrame.withWatermark("time", "10 seconds")
         .groupBy(window(col("time"),"10 seconds","1 second"))
         .agg(mean("col1") with window of 10 seconds,max("col") with window of 5 seconds)`
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple aggregations on different sets of keys (different window = different grouping keys) in a single streaming query is not yet supported. You would have to run 2 different queries.

Comment: Thanks For the Reply. If I go for 2 different queries lets say one for mean and one for max than I'll not be able to join those queries as Joining two streaming queries or data frames is not yet supported for multiple aggregations. Please help me to find a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Where dynamic rules which contains multiple aggregations (Avg, Max,..etc. Spark batch Supported) can not be applied on Spark Structured Streaming until 2.2. 
Even breaking the queries and joining them also Spark considers it as multiple aggregation and throws the exception.

Example from Logical Plan : 
Aggr1: **Aggregate** [EventTime#29, CategoryName#15], [EventTime#29, CategoryName#15, **sum**(ItemValue#10) AS sum(ItemValue)#64]

Aggr2: **Aggregate** [EventTime#84, CategoryName#105], [EventTime#84, CategoryName#105, **avg**(ItemValue#100) AS avg(ItemValue)#78]

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Multiple streaming aggregations are not supported with streaming DataFrames/Datasets;;

Comment: Well thanks for the answer but we already know this. And also we have achieved this using Kafka Streams.